MatrixForm not solving using defined variables
Currently, I'm experiencing an issue when using MatrixForm, I've attached the code that shows the problem, but essentially when trying to get it to solve, it just depicts the equation in terms of constants instead of their defined values. Not sure what changed since when playing around with the code yesterday I did not have this problem.
Constants/Constraints
Rho = 2700; CP = 900; k1 = 240; hg = 500; Tg = 1000; hc = 100; Tc= -200;

Elements and shape functions;
pt = 0.0500;
r1 = 0.0127;
r2 = r1 + pt;
xe1 = {r1, r1 + pt/4, r1 + pt/2};
xe2 = {r1 + pt/2, r1 + (3 pt)/4, r1 + pt};
Ni = (p (p - 1))/2; Nk = (1 + p) (1 - p); Nj = p (p + 1)/2;
shapeN = {{Ni, Nk, Nj}}
Bbar = Simplify[D[shapeN, p]]

Jacobian;
J1 = Simplify[Bbar.xe1][[1]]
J2 = Simplify[Bbar.xe2][[1]]

Make isoparametric formulations: Stiffness Matrix Integrand:
M1 = (shapeN.xe1)[[1]];
Ind1e1 = Rho CP M1 Transpose[shapeN].shapeN J1;
Ind2e1 = k1  M1  Transpose[Bbar].Bbar 1/J1;
M2 = (shapeN.xe2)[[1]];
Ind1e2 = Rho CP M2 Transpose[shapeN].shapeN J2;
Ind2e2 = k1  M2  Transpose[Bbar].Bbar  1/J2;
MatrixForm[Ind1e1]
MatrixForm[Ind2e1]

Any help would be appreciated!!

You did not show your output so it is difficult to understand your problem. Perhaps you were executing some of your comments.
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(* Constants/Constraints *)
Rho = 2700; CP = 900; k1 = 240; hg = 500; 
Tg = 1000; hc = 100; Tc = -200;

(* Elements and shape functions; *)
pt = 0.0500 // Rationalize;
r1 = 0.0127 // Rationalize;
r2 = r1 + pt;
xe1 = {r1, r1 + pt/4, r1 + pt/2};
xe2 = {r1 + pt/2, r1 + (3  pt)/4, r1 + pt};
Ni = (p  (p - 1))/2; Nk = (1 + p)  (1 - p); Nj = p  (p + 1)/2;
shapeN = {{Ni, Nk, Nj}};
Bbar = Simplify[D[shapeN, p]];

(* Jacobian; *)
J1 = Simplify[Bbar . xe1][[1]];
J2 = Simplify[Bbar . xe2][[1]];

(* Make isoparametric formulations:Stiffness Matrix Integrand: *)
M1 = (shapeN . xe1)[[1]];
Ind1e1 = Rho  CP  M1  Transpose[shapeN] . shapeN  J1 // Simplify;
Ind2e1 = k1   M1   Transpose[Bbar] . Bbar  1/J1 // Simplify;
M2 = (shapeN . xe2)[[1]];
Ind1e2 = Rho  CP  M2  Transpose[shapeN] . shapeN  J2 // Simplify;
Ind2e2 = k1   M2   Transpose[Bbar] . Bbar   1/J2 // Simplify;
MatrixForm[Ind1e1]
MatrixForm[Ind2e1]
MatrixForm[Ind1e2]
MatrixForm[Ind2e2]


All of the matrices are functions of p since you have not given p a value
